# How can I find objects that are in BOTH arrays and promptly add it to another array?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I create a method that recieve two arrays as parameters and return an array filled with the items that were in **both** arrays?

Input (Array1 passed in method): ["Lisa", "George", "Mario"]
Input (Array2 passed in method): ["Luigi", "Susan", "Lisa"]

Method should return: ["Lisa"]

I cannot use any built in methods so I have to build my own algorithm, but I'm stuck for the past 2 hours. How can I achieve this in Java?

Edit: Christ on a candle stick. It's not for homework. I'm just real shitty at algorithms. Especially ones as basic as this, and especially on a foreign language I've never used. :P

Comment: If you can't use built in methods, it's homework or an interesting reason.  If it's homework, could you tag it as such?  And if it's something interesting, could you share?

Comment: If it's not homework, why can't you use the collections to best advantage?  Rolling your own is simply wrong in this case.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
private static String[] findCommon(final String[] array1,
        final String[] array2) {
    final Set<String> common = new HashSet<String>();
    common.addAll(Arrays.asList(array1));
    common.retainAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
    return common.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: "...cannot use any built in methods..." - doesn't this preclude using the java.util Collections?

Comment: Hadn't spotted that duffymo. Though, since it isn't homework, I don't understand why this constraint would exist ;-)

Comment: @duffymo, my recommendation for the not-homework would be to look up the definition of the built-in method and then implement that.  toolkit's implementation is sufficient as an algorithm sketch; now the OP just needs to fill in the remaining blanks.  On the not-homework....

Answer (score 3):

One quick way is the following algorithm:

```
For each item in list1, add it to a dictionary.
For each item in list2, check if it exists in dictionary, 
if item exists, add it to list3
else continue.
return list3.
```

Comment: @Alan, I'd recommend that you replace "dictionary" with "set" (assuming that we're not always talking about words).

Comment: Thanks @Bob, however this was a more generalized algorithm, not pertaining to any language.

Comment: @Alan: "set" is a more general term than "dictionary".  Besides, a dictionary is a mapping from keys to values, and you don't need a mapping ... just a set.

Comment: @Alan: "set" is a more (programming) language independent term than "dictionary". Besides, a dictionary is a mapping from keys to values, and you don't need a mapping ... just a set.

Comment: @Stephen C: once is enough.  You almost repeated the same thing word for word.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force.

Loop over the first array.  Inside that loop, have another over the second array.  Compare entries from both, adding them to a new array if you get a match.

Comment: Brute force is O(N*2).  A solution using sets is O(N) or O(NlogN) depending on which Set implementation you use (and on certain other assumptions).

Comment: Agreed, but he said he couldn't use built-in functions, so I assumed that precluding using java.util Collections.  And certainly for the small example cases he presented the Big-Oh notation is irrelevant.  Alan's answer is pretty much the same as mine - two nested loops - and it's been voted up three times.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [] result = ...

    foreach( itemA in a ) {
        foreach(  iteamB in b ) {
             if( itemB == itemA ) { // if they are in both places
                   r[] = itemB // append it to the result
             }
         }
    }
    return result;
```